# Проблема с обработкой запроса post в Node

Tags: node.js

Отправляю из сайта post запрос, он доходит возвращает статус код 200, дальше мне нужно данные отправленные при запросе записать в файл.

```
if (request.method == 'POST') {
    let body = ''
    request.on('data', chunk =>{
        body += chunk.toString()
    })
    request.on('end', () => {
        let params = parse(body)
        console.log(params)
        let fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFileSync('Newdata.json',params)
        response.end('post')
    })
}
```

Такой алгоритм не работает, сегодня начал учить ноду так что буду рад помощи.

запрос

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3001',{name:'superhero', age: 18}).then(response => (console.log(response)));
```

выводит в консоль `[Object: nill prototype]{ '{{"name":"superhero", "age": 18}}':''}` и достать данные не получаеться.

С сервером я не работал много, дальше мне нужно будет брать данные из этого файла так что можете и тут помочь))

Comment: ракомендую строчку let fs = require('fs') писать в начале файла, а не в обработчике on end, чтобы данное действие было выполнено 1 раз, а не на каждый запрос

Comment: Я, кроме как посоветовать использовать `express` пожалуй ничего не могу.

Comment: @MoloF дело говоришь

Answer (score 0):

Можете ли вы подробнее описать, что вам нужно сделать и какой результат хотите получить? Просто у меня после попытки написать тот же код, что и у вас получается следующее:

1. На сервер приходит POST запрос.
2. Считывается `body` в обработчике `data`.
3. В `end` обработчике парсится string в javascript объект.
4. Javascript объект синхронно пишется в файл (что, не очень хорошо, лучше использовать асинхронную реализацию).
5. `res.end` возвращает строку `post` как результат запроса.

Что касается `console.log` в `axios.post(...).then()`, то у меня выводится прямо полное тело ответа. Для того, чтобы получить конкретно данные (то, что отправлено в `res.end`), нужно брать `response.data`. Но опять же, по вопросу непонятно, что именно вы хотите возвращать как response POST запроса.

Ну и еще пара замечаний по коду:

1. Как заметили в комментариях, `require` лучше всегда делать в начале
   файла. И один раз.
2. Для `params` можно спокойно использовать `const`
   вместо `let`, так как они не изменяются.
3. Ну и да, классика: всегда
   используйте тройное равенство (https://habr.com/ru/post/138272/) -
   одна из множества статей, в которой объясняется, почему.